# Dynamically fetch data in parent component when new data is added in child component in Vue without using watcher

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component, vuetify.js

Is there any way in Vue to display the data when it is updated other than using watcher ? Just like we have useEffect in React which renders when the data is changed, is there anyway we can do something similar without using Watcher ? Because watcher is taking dedicated resources for continuously watching over the state.

I am want to display the name of the user on the left side as soon as user enter the same in some other page.

Alternative of Watcher in Vue

Here's the code

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <q-layout view="hHh lpR lFf">
            <!-- Header -->
            <q-header elevated :class="$q.dark.isActive ? 'bg-secondary' : 'bg-black'">
                <q-toolbar>
                    <q-btn flat @click="drawer = !drawer" round dense icon="menu"></q-btn>
                    <q-toolbar-title>Data Templates</q-toolbar-title>
                </q-toolbar>
            </q-header>

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <q-page-container>
                <router-view></router-view>
                <CreateTemplate v-if="showCreateTemplate" />
                <EditTemplate v-if="showEditTemplate" :id="template._id" />
                <DeleteTemplate v-if="showEditTemplate" :id="template._id" />
                <SpecificTemplate v-if="showEditTemplate" :id="template._id" />
            </q-page-container>

            <!-- Sidebar -->
            <q-drawer v-model="drawer" show-if-above class="drawer">
                <q-scroll-area class="fit">
                    <div class="sidebar">
                        <div class="sidebar-content">
                            <q-btn class="data-button" color="primary" label="Create New Template" dense
                                @click="navigateTo()" />
                            <div class="template-list">
                                <q-item v-for="(templateItem) in template" :key="templateItem._id">
                                    <q-item-section>
                                        <div class="template-item">
                                            <div @click="gotoSpecificTemplate(templateItem._id)">{{ templateItem.name ?
                                                templateItem.name : "No Name" }}</div>
                                            <div class="template-buttons">
                                                <q-btn color="red" dense
                                                    @click="navigateDeleteTo(templateItem._id)">
                                                    <font-awesome-icon icon="trash" class="template-icon" />
                                                </q-btn>
                                                <q-btn color="primary" dense
                                                    @click="navigateEditTo(templateItem._id)">
                                                    <font-awesome-icon icon="pen" class="template-icon" />
                                                </q-btn>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </q-item-section>
                                </q-item>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </q-scroll-area>
            </q-drawer>
        </q-layout>
    </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>
import CreateTemplate from '../components/MainLayout.vue';
import EditTemplate from '../components/EditLayout.vue';
import DeleteTemplate from '../components/DeleteLayout.vue';
import SpecificTemplate from '../components/SpecificLayout.vue';

import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted, watch } from 'vue';
import {
    QLayout,
    QDrawer,
    QScrollArea,
    QToolbarTitle,
    QItem,
    QBtn,
} from 'quasar';
import axios from 'axios';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { faTrash, faPen } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';

library.add(faTrash, faPen);

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'AppLayout',
    components: {
        QLayout,
        QDrawer,
        QScrollArea,
        QToolbarTitle,
        QItem,
        QBtn,
        CreateTemplate,
        EditTemplate,
        FontAwesomeIcon,
        DeleteTemplate,
        SpecificTemplate

    },
    setup() {
        const drawer = ref(false);
        const buttonData = ref([]);
        const text = ref('');
        const template = ref([]);
        const showCreateTemplate = ref(false);
        const showEditTemplate = ref(false);
        const showDeleteTemplate = ref(false);
        const showSpecificTemplate = ref(false);
        const router = useRouter();

        const fetchAllTemplates = async () => {
            try {
                const templateResponse = await axios.get('https://my-api.com/templates');
                const templates = templateResponse.data;
                template.value = templates;
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching templates: ', error);
            }
        };

        onMounted(() => {
            fetchAllTemplates();
        });

        watch(template, () => {
            fetchAllTemplates();
        });

        const navigateTo = () => {
            router.push({ name: 'create-template' });
            showCreateTemplate.value = false;
            showEditTemplate.value = false;
        }

        const navigateEditTo = (templateId) => {
            router.push({ name: 'update-template', params: { id: templateId } });
            showEditTemplate.value = false;
        };

        const navigateDeleteTo = (templateId) => {
            router.push({name: 'delete-template', params: {id: templateId}});
            showDeleteTemplate.value = false;

        }
        const gotoSpecificTemplate = (templateId) => {
            try {
                router.push({ name: 'specific-template', params: { id: templateId } });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('There is some error: ', error);
            }
        };

        return {
            drawer,
            buttonData,
            text,
            template,
            showCreateTemplate,
            showEditTemplate,
            showDeleteTemplate,
            showSpecificTemplate,
            navigateTo,
            navigateEditTo,
            gotoSpecificTemplate,
            navigateDeleteTo
        };
    },
});
</script>
```

Comment: There are "computed" properties. This is from vue 2 documentation, but i think it's gonna be the same for vue 3. https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: Consider explaining your case further. You may need a computed or watcher depending on it. "Because watcher is taking dedicated resources for continuously watching over the state" - not really, it takes resources to watch over the changes in a part of the state you specify in an input, it's efficient by design.

Comment: I have one parent component and one child component. There is a button on child component where on clicking it, it saves the data to the db ( name, age and username ). Now I want to fetch the name from the db in parent component as soon as the save button is clicked in child component. I am using watcher which basically watches the fetch api in parent and displays the name as soon as there's a change. So here I want to fetch only when there's some change unlike watcher which repeatedly fetches or refreshes the parent component.

Comment: Please include a **minimal** reproducible example. There's a lot in your code that we don't need and this makes it hard to find and focus on the important parts; for example, Font Awesome icons. And maybe add some dummy data for the API dependent function.

Comment: _"Just like we have useEffect in React which renders when the data is changed, is there anyway we can do something similar without using Watcher ? Because watcher is taking dedicated resources for continuously watching over the state."_ Watchers (`watch`/`watchEffect`) are _not_ inefficient: the whole system uses native JS Proxies under the hood; a browser-managed event system, basically. It does not use _polling_, which seems to be the implementation you are implying.

Comment: @OjasAklecha _"I want to fetch only when there's some change unlike watcher which repeatedly fetches or refreshes the parent component."_ What do you mean by this? A watcher is triggered only when its source(s) have changed. If it's triggering repeatedly, that means that your are updating the source(s) repeatedly.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes I mean to say watcher repeatedly looks for changes and make changes when there's some changes. I don't want my component to be watched continuously. It should be changed when there's some change.

Comment: @OjasAklecha I'm afraid that makes no sense. It makes changes when there's changes, but you only want it to make changes when something has changed?

Comment: @OjasAklecha _"Now I want to fetch the name from the db in parent component as soon as the save button is clicked in child component."_ What about using an [event](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html)?

Comment: @DarrylNoakes I changed the code. I emitted a Boolean value from one component I wanted to the parent component. when that Boolean is true, it will fetch the data from the api. Now it is fetching when I am clicking some button which is triggering the emit

Comment: @OjasAklecha So is it working now? If you've found a solution, you can write a self answer.

Comment: Please post your answer **as an answer,** not an edit. This keeps the question and answers separated, allows people to vote on your solution, makes the solution more visible to others, and allows this Q&A to be marked as answered. If you do not, as a last resort I may post it as an answer of my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. What I did was I emitted a Boolean value from child component. That value is initially false. When a button is clicked in child component, it is converted into true and sent to the parent component. In parent component, I used method instead of setup, to fetch the data using fetch function ( I took it out of setup and placed it in methods only ) when the Boolean value received from the child component is true. I used async functions and await to make it smooth like when api display only when api is called and meanwhile wait for it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

`computed` can track `ref` change.
here is example.

type `aaaa` input field.

```js
const { createApp, ref, computed } = Vue

createApp({
  setup() {
    const value = ref('')
    const userList = [{ user: 'aaaa' }, { user: 'bbbb' }]
    
    const user = computed(() => userList.find((el) => el.user === value.value))
    
    return {
      value,
      user,
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="value" />
  {{ user }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain js you could create a Proxy and make it execute code on change.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: Which is how the whole Vue reactivity system works. This is what a watcher does.

Comment: Exactly, thus, not using the watcher Vue provides (which would take more resources). No reason to down-vote as I simply stated an alternative to the watcher method.

Comment: I did not downvote; there are not even any votes on your question at all. My point was that, once you have implemented everything necessary, a watcher doesn't have much more overhead; they also integrate with the the reactivity system much better (obviously). And, if what is being watched is something reactive, then it makes sense to simply use the reactivity system primitives.

Comment: Overall, I believe that performance is not the real issue the OP is facing; it appears to be a misunderstanding of how the reactivity system works and how to use it (or a misuse of it).